# Regex to match movie file

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to write some regex to match the title of a movie from a file. The regex should match the title from all the example files. I can only get it to work for some of them currently with this regex `^(.+).(\d{4}p)`.
I am using this in Java from the package java.util.regex

I would like it to work when the movie file format is:

- {title} {year} {resolution} etc.
- {title} {resolution} {year} etc.
- {title} {resolution} etc.
- {title} {year} etc.
- when the movie contains a year or is just a year like the movie: 2012 (2009)

**Example files:**

```
Film.2017.720p.BluRay.H264.AAC.mp4
Film.And.The.Film.2017.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4
152.Seconds.2010.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4
2015.2005.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<String> movies = new ArrayList<>();
    movies.add("Film.2017.720p.BluRay.H264.AAC.mp4");
    movies.add("Film.And.The.Film.2017.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4");
    movies.add("152.Seconds.2010.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4");
    movies.add("2015.2005.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4");

    for (String s : movies)
    {
        System.out.println("original file: \t" + s);
        System.out.println("new file: \t\t" + getTitleFromFile(s) + "\n");
    }
}
    

private static String getTitleFromFile(String fileName)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+).(\\d{4}p)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(fileName);

    if (m.find())
    {
        return m.group();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Actual Output:

```
original file:  Film.2017.720p.BluRay.H264.AAC.mp4
new file:       null

original file:  Film.And.The.Film.2017.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4
new file:       null

original file:  Film 2015 1080p BluRay x264 DTS.mp4
new file:       Film 2015 1080p

original file:  Film.1080p.BrRip.x264.mp4
new file:       Film.1080p
```

Expected Output:

```
original file:  Film.2017.720p.BluRay.H264.AAC.mp4
new file:       Film

original file:  Film.And.The.Film.2017.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4
new file:       Film And The Film

original file:  Film 2015 1080p BluRay x264 DTS.mp4
new file:       Film

original file:  Film.1080p.BrRip.x264.mp4
new file:       Film
```

Comment: I'm using java with the regex

Comment: I think I have done this now, thank you

Comment: Great Conor. I spent some time on this problem. It would be nice of you if you can confirm what I found now matches your expectation. I tested using ur code with this pattern - "^(.+).(\\d{4}|\\d{3,4}p)" and I am getting output as follows - American.Made.2017.720p , Valerian.And.The.City.Of.A.Thousand.Planets.2017.1080p , 127.Hours.2010.1080p , 2012.2009.1080p Isnt this what you want ?

Comment: Hi @rootkonda That isn't entirely what I'm looking for but thank you anyway. I edited the post to clarify what I expect the output to look like. However your regex is closer to what I'm looking for than what I originally had!

Comment: ok got it. Thanks for the reply Conor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.*?)\W(?:(\d{4})(?:\W(\d+p)?)|(\d+p)(?:\W(\d{4}))?)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IRZJlw/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: name, any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\W` - a non-word char
- `(?:(\d{4})(?:\W(\d+p)?)|(\d+p)(?:\W(\d{4}))?)` - either of

  - `(\d{4})(?:\W(\d+p)?)` - Group 2 - four digits followed with an optional group matching a non-word char and then one or more digits and `p` captured in Group 3
  - `|` - or
  - `(\d+p)(?:\W(\d{4}))?` - Group 4 - one or more digits and `p` followed with an optional group matching a non-word char and then four digits captured in Group 5
- `\b` - word boundary

Java demo:

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("Film.The.Film.720p.BrRip.x264.BOKUTOX.mp4",
         "Film.The.Film.2020.BrRip.x264.mp4",
         "Film.The.Film.720p.2020.BrRip.x264.mp4", 
         "Film.The.Film.720p.BrRip.x264.mp4");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)\\W(?:(\\d{4})(?:\\W(\\d+p)?)|(\\d+p)(?:\\W(\\d{4}))?)\\b");
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("\n--------\nName: " + m.group(1).replace(".", " "));
        if (m.group(2) != null) {
            System.out.println("Year: " + m.group(2));
            if (m.group(3) != null) {
                System.out.println("Resolution: " + m.group(3));
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Resolution: " + m.group(4));
            if (m.group(5) != null) {
                System.out.println("Year: " + m.group(5));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--------
Name: Film The Film
Year: 2004
Resolution: 720p

--------
Name: Film The Film
Year: 2020

--------
Name: Film The Film
Resolution: 720p
Year: 2020

--------
Name: Film The Film
Resolution: 720p
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this worked perfectly!